# Создание метода класса

Tags: c++, visual-studio, классы, указатели, vector

Имеется класс, полем которого является структура, а один из методов это работа с этой структурой. При инициализации метода ругается на неправильное объявление, не могу понять как исправить. Что нужно написать, чтобы заработал?
Спасибо
(метод без параметров, выдает указатель на вектор типа структура)

Заголовок класса:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class polygone
{
private:
typedef struct pointXY
{
    double x;
    double y;
}pole;

public:
polygone();
~polygone();
polygone unn(polygone *pol1, polygone *pol2);
const std::vector<pole*>& polygone::poly() const;
};
```

Реализация метода:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "polygone.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern struct pole;

polygone::polygone() {
poly();
}


polygone::~polygone()
{
}

polygone polygone::unn(polygone * pol1, polygone * pol2)
{
return polygone();
}

const std::vector<pole*>& polygone::poly() const{
ifstream file("poly.txt");
vector<string> vals;
vector<pole*> pgn;
pole *polyget = new pole;
if (file.is_open()) {
    string s;
    int counter1 = 0;
    while (getline(file, s, ';'))
    {
        vals.push_back(s);
    }
    file.close();
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.size(); i += 2) {
        polyget->x = atof(vals[i - 1].c_str());
        pgn.push_back(polyget);
        polyget->y = atof(vals[i].c_str());
        pgn.push_back(polyget);
    }
}
else {
    //cout << "Open error!";
}
return pgn;
}
```

[Ругается вот на эти места, что на картинке:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyOty.png)

Comment: `extern struct pole` это что вообще ? Вы сказали компилятору что у вас где-то есть структура `pole`, и ваш метод возращает вектор таких структур. В заголовочном файле класса вы сказали что этот же метод должен возвращать вложенную в `polygone` структуру `pole`, то есть в заголовке ваш метод возвращает `std::vector<polygone::pole>`, а в реализации `std::vector<pole>`, где `pole` - нечто, что требуется найти в другом файле исходников

Comment: этим действом я хотел передать структуру из заголовка класса в файл инициализации методов

Comment: Вы подключили заголовочный файл, в котором уже объявлена эта структура. В файл реализации методов, а не в файл инициализации методов оО

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно такого объявления внутренней структуры:

```
class polygone
{
private:
    struct pole
    {
        double x;
        double y;
    };

public:
    polygone();
...
```

Внутри класса в объявлении не нужно указывать сам класс:

```
const std::vector<pole*>& poly() const;
```

Зато вне класса нужно полностью указать имя внутренней структуры:

```
const std::vector<polygone::pole*>& polygone::poly() const
```

Объявление не пойми чего

```
extern struct pole;
```

не нужно.

И еще - вот тут

```
const std::vector<polygone::pole*>& polygone::poly() const
```

вы возвращаете *ссылку* на локальный объект. Что очень плохо... Вот так лучше:

```
std::vector<polygone::pole*> polygone::poly() const
```

Да, и еще - стоит ли делать тип `pole` закрытым (`private`), если вы планируете с ним работать вне класса? Например, вы не сможете написать

```
polygone p;
vector<polygone::pole*> s = p.poly();
```

Правда, все равно сможете написать

```
polygone p;
auto s = p.poly();
```

Но какой смысл скрывать то, что хотите видеть **вне** класса?

Comment: Большое спасибо!! Все сделал - вроде работает:)
То есть структуру лучше будет объявить в "рубрике" public, а не private?

Comment: Если вы планируете, что с ней будет работа **вне** вашего класса - мне кажется, лучше сделать ее открытой. Смотрите сами - общих правил не так уж много, и всегда есть исключения :) Если ответ устроил полностью - можете закрывать вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый.

Comment: А можно такой вопрос: как теперь вот это значение pgn, которое вернула функция, получить в главном окне программы?

Comment: Вы уж извините, но я ничего не знаю ни о вашей программе, ни о ее главном окне. Код получения в какую-то переменную я привел - простое присваивание типа `vector<polygone::pole*> s = p.poly();`, ну а дальше делайте с ним, что вам нужно...

Comment: Благодарю, это то, что я и хотел узнать!